# Couchbase basic bucket N1QL query NodeJS script not returning any value

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have a basic NodeJS Couchbase script straight from their documentation. It just inserts a document and immediately N1QL queries the inserted document.

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase')
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost/');
cluster.authenticate('admin', 'admini');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('application');
var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;

bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex(function() {
  bucket.upsert('user:king_arthur', {
    'email': 'kingarthur@couchbase.com', 'interests': ['Holy Grail', 
   'African Swallows']
  },
  function (err, result) {
    bucket.get('user:king_arthur', function (err, result) {
      console.log('Got result: %j', result.value);
      bucket.query(
        N1qlQuery.fromString('SELECT * FROM application WHERE $1 in 
      interests LIMIT 1'),
      ['African Swallows'],
      function (err, rows) {
       console.log("Got rows: %j", rows);
     });
   });
 });
});
```

This is returning back

```
bash-3.2$ node nodejsTest.js  Got result:
      {"email":"kingarthur@couchbase.com","interests":["Holy 
      Grail","African Swallows"]} 
      Got rows: []
```

I was expecting the inserted document in the "rows" array.

Any idea why this very basic nodeJS starter script is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key/value read writes are always consistent (that is, if you write a document, then retrieve it by ID, you will always get back what you just wrote).  However, updating an index for N1QL queries takes time and can affect performance.

As of version 5.0, you can control your consistency requirements to balance the trade-off between performance and consistency.  By default, Couchbase uses the `Not_bounded` mode.  In this mode, queries are executed immediately, without waiting for indexing to catch up.  This causes the issue you're seeing.  Your query is executing before the index has been updated with the mutation you made.

You can read about this further here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/indexes/performance-consistency.html